# LINQ Join Method for joining on referenced properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following piece of code which is actually from a third party library.I'm trying to build a dictionary which contains keys as the security keys and the values as the market name. How can I do it efficiently using LINQ methods? Please note that the collections are pretty huge - for ex there are around 10K security objects.The issue I'm facing is that the security key is not a property on market object, but rather it's inside security object. Please can you help? A security can have only one country assigned to it, and the country belongs to one market.

```
   interface IKey{int Id { get; set; }}
   interface ISecurityKey:IKey{}
   interface ICountryKey:IKey{}
   interface IMarketKey:IKey{}

   class Security
   {
       public ISecurityKey SecuirtyKey { get; set; }
       public ICountryKey CountryKey { get; set; }
   }  
   class Country
   {
       public ICountryKey CountryKey { get; set; }
       public IMarketKey MarketKey { get; set; }        
   }

   class Market
   {
       public IMarketKey MarketKey { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   interface IThirdPartyApiWhichICannotChange
   {
       List<IKey> GetAllSecurityKeys();
       Dictionary<IKey, Security> GetAllSecurities(List<IKey> securityKeys);
       Dictionary<IKey, Country> GetAllCountries(List<IKey> countryKeys);
       Dictionary<IKey, Market> GetAllMArkets(List<IKey> marketKeys);
   }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var service = new ThirdPartyApiWhichICannotChange();

            var securityKeys = service.GetAllSecurityKeys();
            var securities   = service.GetAllSecurities(securityKeys);
            var countries    = service.GetAllCountries(securities.Values.Select(x => x.CountryKey).Cast<IKey>().ToList());
            var markets      = service.GetAllMArkets(countries.Values.Select(x => x.MarketKey).Cast<IKey>().ToList());

            //How do I build a dictionary with securitykey as the key and the market name as the value?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
list<Item> = securities.Select(s => new Item(s.SecurityKey, markets.First(m => m.marketKey == countries.First(c => c.countryKey == s.CountryKey).MarketKey)).marketName)
```

You iterate through all securities and find the corresponding country / market.
You should define item as a class containing a securityKey and a string